# Is there any way to change the nginx path in centos for web development?

Tags: centos, nginx

Using LEMP in CENTOS 7 the route to deploy web projects is:

**`/usr/share/nginx/html`**

i can have it changed to:

**`/var/www/html`**?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` for the `root` directive and change it there.